# "Magento supports PHP 7.0.2, 7.0.4, and 7.0.6" error message when I have PHP 7.2.12

Tags: magento2, php-7

Having installed the DB for Magento 2.2.6 I get this error message when trying to initiate setup;

http://www.ben-grant.co.uk/magento226/

"Magento supports PHP 7.0.2, 7.0.4, and 7.0.6 or later. Please read Magento System Requirements."

The version of PHP I am running is 7.2.12 so wondered if anyone would know why this error is occurring?

Comment: That specific Magento version needs a specific PHP version. So you should downgrade your PHP version or upgrade Magento to 2.3

Answer (score 0):

**You can change PHP version 7.1.x to fix the issue.**

Also read devdocs system-requirements:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Hope it helps!