# Upgrading to Magento 2.3.3 gives a php version error

Tags: magento2, php

When I access my website I get the php v error

```
Magento supports PHP 7.1.3 or later. Please read Magento System Requirements.
```

But I have php 7.3.13

[image]

What am I missing?

I have checked these documentation but it didn't help.
[When trying to upgrade to 2.3.2 getting a php version error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281049/when-trying-to-upgrade-to-2-3-2-getting-a-php-version-error?rq=1)

["Magento supports PHP 7.0.2, 7.0.4, and 7.0.6" error message when I have PHP 7.2.12](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252062/magento-supports-php-7-0-2-7-0-4-and-7-0-6-error-message-when-i-have-php-7-2)

https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2-x/Magento-2-3-quot-Magento-supports-PHP-7-0-2-7-0-4-and-7-0-6-or/td-p/119379

Comment: Can you also confirm that the webserver is running PHP 7.3.x? I'd recommend adding a line `<?php phpinfo();exit; ?>` on the first line of `{magento_root}/pub/index.php` so it'll load a `phpinfo` page and show you what's actually running via the server.

Comment: can you check with php cli version?

Comment: Yeah the Core was running 7.0.33. After updating it works perfectly. Thanks :)